# Mongoose connecting even when DB String is wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

database.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const connectDB=()=>{
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB,()=>{
    console.log("CONNECTED TO DATABASE")
})
}

module.exports=connectDB
```

server.js

```
const app=require('./app')
const dotenv=require('dotenv')
const connectDB=require('./config/database')

dotenv.config({path:"config/dotenv.env"})

connectDB()


app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`CONNECTED TO SERVER ON PORT : ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode `);
});
```

Now the DB inside my config.env file, even If I change it to the wrong string , to get promise rejection , I still get the "CONNECTED TO DATABASE" logged to the console.
It does not show the error, but the requests to routes in postman gets stuck on loading.
What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The callback you provide to the connect() function gets executed also if the connection fails.

This would prevent logging the message to the console in such cases:

```
const connectDB = () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, (error) => {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("CONNECTED TO DATABASE")
        }
    })
}
```